# Are "how can I modify my recipe to achieve X" questions off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I have a recipe that I want to modify to make it more fluffy/modify the flavors of, and I'm curious whether the modifications I plan to attempt will have my desired effect.  I'm worried, however, that a question of this nature will be too "opinion-based"

Can I list out my modifications, and ask whether they have the effect I want?  Can I ask what would be good temperatures/ratios for my modifications?  Could I ask what other sorts of recipe modifications would have the desired effect I am looking for?

Answer (score 7):

This is a good type of question, and not at all off topic. We would be happy to have it.

The one caveat is that you should know what "X" is and be able to describe it. So, question which work well would say something like:

> Here's the recipe for my sweet oven omelette with strawberries. I want it to be fluffier and for the strawberry taste to come more through, what can I change?

What does not work is simply wanting it "better" but not defining what you consider to be better. "Less bland", "Take it up a notch", "Something's missing", "I want it to be more interesting" are bad ways to ask the question and will likely be closed as opinion-based.

The difference between the two is that phrases like "more strawberry flavor" or "fluffier" are descriptions of the food, and everybody knows what they mean. Phrases like "tastier" or "more interesting" are description of *your personal evaluation of the food* and so impossible to answer, as 1) we don't know your taste, and 2) even for a given taste, there are dozens if not hundreds different ways to achieve an evaluation like "tasty".

I hope this makes it clearer how to word a good question. If not, you are still welcome to post it. If it strays into too-broad category, we're happy to work with you on focusing it better instead of closing. We only close when it is obvious that the OP doesn't really have a clear idea of what he wants, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: The most common category of bad "will this work" questions is "will this dish work?", e.g. "will this chicken marinade work with pork?", where the OP is actually just asking "will this dish taste good?" -- but indeed that is clearly not what the OP here is asking, so all is well.